# Assign a value to NA rows by creating new variable

Tags: r, na

I'm trying to assign a spesific value to NA rows by creating new variable.

My dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(A = c(1, 0, NA, 1, NA),
                 B = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 0),
                 C = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0))
```

Desired output:

| A | B | C | group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| NA | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| NA | 0 | 0 | 1 |

Basically, if there is NA in the first column, this observation is in group `1`.

Comment: `df$group <- as.numeric(is.na(df$A))`

Comment: Another solution: `df$group <- match(df$A, NA, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

with `dplyr` just use `mutate` with `is.na`:

```
df |>
    mutate(group = + is.na(A))

# OR

df |>
    mutate(group = as.numeric(is.na(A)))
```